# lightinng:listview component is showing error "The list view you requested was deleted, or you don't have permission to view it"

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightninglistview

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader" access="global">  

    <lightning:listView aura:id="listViewAccounts" objectApiName="Account"
           listName="AllAccounts" rows="5" showActionBar="false"
           enableInlineEdit="true" showRowLevelActions="false"/>

</aura:component>
```

I am using sample code provide by documentation to view list views. But getting error on UI "*The list view you requested was deleted, or you don't have permission to view it.*"

I have added component in contact detail page in lightning.

Comment: [Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:listView/documentation) says: `If an invalid objectApiName or listName value is used, an error displays.`

Comment: I have used code given by documentation itself. I tried with different combination of objects by querying 'select id, developername from listview', but all in pain.

Comment: you're right, looks like bug or we are missing something small.

Comment: Is your org namespace enabled?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what I observed while testing this out. I tried the same snippet as in the post and received the same error. After few attempts, realized that if at all your org is namespace enabled (mine is), **you will need to prefix the namespace to the list view name**.

***This behavior is definitely not mentioned in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:listView/documentation) (as of today)***.

So if your org is namespace enabled, then in order to get this component to work, the code needs to be modified to prefix the namespace in the `listName` attribtue, something as below:

```
<lightning:listView aura:id="listViewAccounts" objectApiName="Account"
           listName="mynamespace__AllAccounts" rows="5" showActionBar="false"
           enableInlineEdit="true" showRowLevelActions="false"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

@jayant Solution is correct, I just wanted to add some more info here. 
 If we query ListView Object then we can query

```
SELECT DeveloperName,NamespacePrefix,SobjectType FROM ListView
```

Then while fetching ListView if Namespaceprefix exist in apex can add  `NamespacePrefix+__+DeveloperName` in apex and pass it to Lightning.

So in lightning

```
<lightning:listView aura:id="listViewAccounts" objectApiName="Account"
           listName="NamespacePrefix+__+DeveloperName" rows="5" showActionBar="false" enableInlineEdit="true" showRowLevelActions="false"/>
```

Above approach will work for all cases.